# How do we deploy a Worklight server in IBM Bluemix platform?

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, containers, ibm-cloud, worklight-server

Can we deploy Worklight server in [IBM Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) platform?

Is that supported currently in Bluemix?

How can I deploy a Worklight application in Bluemix environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, It is not possible to use the current release of Worklight ("on prem") and use it in Bluemix ("on cloud").

In the coming weeks Worklight will/should/may be available as a mobile service in Bluemix.
You will need to wait a little bit longer.

---

Update01:
As others mentioning below, now you are able to run worklight inside a Bluemix container. You do not have to install the platform, it is all done automatically.
[image]
More info on [Bluemix container here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Worklight is available in Container in Bluemix with name Mobile First Bluemix Container.

This is Beta and very soon it will be come GA.

You can host your Hybrid Apps and Adapters on this.

Answer (score 2):

I see this question is from 8 months ago, currently you are able to run worklight inside a Bluemix container. 
You do not have to install the platform, it is all done atumatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported at this time. You can take a look at this thread for some more details: 
   https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10180/worklight-app-to-be-deployed-in-bluemix/

Answer (score 0):

worklight is not supported on Bluemix PAAS currently,however in future it may be included.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10180/worklight-app-to-be-deployed-in-bluemix.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no buildpack for Worklight Server so you cannot currently run a Worklight server application on BlueMix.

Answer (score 0):

Buildpack is still not for Worklight server so you cannot run a Worklight server application on BlueMix. However you can run your .war file created in WorkLight studio in liberty of java buildpack on BlueMix.

for more details please follow below link:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10180/worklight-app-to-be-deployed-in-bluemix.html